# Alterar URL de acesso ao Admin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Galera, é o seguinte: crio diversos sites e sistemas, e a maioria deles existe a área administrativa. Eu faço até então no básico de ser "urldosite.com.br/**admin**".

Agora, por questão de segurança também, quero começar trocar esses acessos. Exemplo, ao invés de ser "**admin**" ser "**admin0978**", mas ai em cada sistema os números serão diferentes.

Como faço isso no CakePHP 3? Como alterar URL de acesso ao Admin no Cakephp 3? Só conseguir até agora precisando alterar todos *namespace* dos controllers do admin.

Comment: Não precisaria modificar os nomes dos controladores e namespaces.. Basta configurar rotas: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: Daniel, vc pode me dá uma luz de como fazer? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

No seu arquivo Project/config/routes.php

```
...
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    ...
    $routes->connect('/admin0978', ['plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index']);
    ...
});
...
```

Comment: Eu uso no routes.php assim:

`
Router::prefix('admin', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/logout', ['controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'logout']);
}
`

Então esse seu jeito não acredito que irá funcionar.

Comment: Mude o prefix então amigo. Mude para ```Router::prefix('admin0987' ....```. Funciona sim, o cake tem várias formas de fazer isso.

Comment: Mas se eu alterar do jeito que você falou, o cake começa pedi que eu crie a pasta Admin0987 dentro da pasta Controller.

`Error: Create the class UsuariosController below in file: src\Controller\Admin0987\UsuariosController.php`